# What might be wrong in this php code?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This code when opened in the browser, displays "Reply button not pressed!" at first when the page loads, and After text is entered and `Post` button is pressed, The text isn't inserted into the database:
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Some Title</title></head>
<body>
<div class="bottom">
<form action="#reply" method='post'>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Post">
</form>
</div>
<a id="reply" href="#" class="popup"></a>
<div class="popup">
<div class="title"><h3>Reply to this Topic</h3></div>
<div class="itopic">
    <p>What would you think about this?</p>
    <form name="pform" method="post" action="">

     <tr>
        <td><textarea name="text" placeholder="Enter your thoughtful response here!" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea></td>
     </tr>
     <br>
     <tr>
        <input type="submit" name="reply" class="tbutton" value="Reply"/>
     </tr>
    </form>
</div>


    <a class="close x" href="#">x</a>

</div>
<?php
$id=$_GET['id']; //id fetched from the URL
if(isset($_POST['reply']) && !empty($_POST['reply']))
{
    $conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','forum') or die(mysql_error());
    if(!strlen(trim($_POST['text']))>0)
    {
        echo "Reply!";
    }
    else
    {
        $stmt= $conn->prepare("INSERT into messages(id,text) VALUES(?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('is',$id1,$text);
        if(isset($_POST['text'])){ $tag = $_POST['text']; } 
        $id1=$id;
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }   
    header("Location: forum.php");
    }
    else{
        echo"Reply button Not pressed!";
}       
?>
</body>
</html>
```

What might be wrong in this php code?
Database details:

1. Database Name: forum
2. Table name: messages

columns-

1. id (foreign key referring to topicID in a different table)
2. time (Default being set to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
3. text

PS: I'm new to php. So help is really appreciated

Comment: `mysql_error()` will not work with the MySQLi API.

Comment: Try this if(isset($_POST['reply']) && $_POST['reply'] != "")

Comment: First in your code $id will not get from form as you are not passing it in GET request.

Comment: You've a lot of syntax errors here and not bothering to check for errors anywhere.

Comment: I think it's that not all browsers send the values associated with "submit" inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the error is in this line:

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){ $tag = $_POST['text']; }
```

it should be

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){ $text = $_POST['text']; }
```

instead, since you require the parameter $text and not $tag.

I would also set this line

```
$stmt->bind_param('is',$id1,$text);
```

after this line:

```
$id1=$id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your ID will be a text string and not an integer so the bind_param() function will fail. Try casting the id as an integer.

```
$id=$_GET['id']; //id fetched from the URL
$id = (int) $id;
```

Comment: You are correct but I was just being modest. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your redirect command (`header("Location: forum.php");`), It's in the wrong place there

Comment: That's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Please do not guess.